# Will php error reporting also display mysql errors?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, apache

I have this in my PHP code, which outputs MySql errors:

```
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Will disabling error reporting in php.ini cause these mysql errors not to show as well?

Comment: How about trying it out? Could very well be faster than asking here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, because *die()* prints the string and exit. This has nothing to do with *error_reporting*. For production environment you should think about a logger to write such message to a file or somewhere, instead of printing it.